# Overriding "@package_version@" in PHPUnit output when installing from Git repo

Tags: php, git, phpunit

I added PHPUnit to a project via `git submodule add` per the instructions in [this blog post](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/getting-phpunit-setup-from-git).  Everything is working beautifully, except the output at the top of each execution looks like this:

> PHPUnit @package_version@ by Sebastian Bergmann.

It looks like PEAR replaces that value with the version number during its install process, which doesn't help me much since I'm using Git to install the files.

Has anyone encountered this issue, and how did you solve/work around it?

Comment: Whats the matter with PEAR? Its the prefered and (in the meantime) only official supported way to install PHPUnit.

Comment: @KingCrunch Nobody said there was anything wrong with PEAR.  I prefer to bundle external dependencies with my project so I can control the versions it deploys with (good justification for this can be found in the documentation for [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html)).  If I can have a build script trigger PEAR to install a particular version of PHPUnit into the project's subdirectory (i.e., without disrupting any existing version a user might already have installed), then I am definitely interested.

Comment: It's also helpful if you want to run the latest version from Git from, say, NetBeans. It chokes because it cannot confirm the PHPUnit version rather than just running and hoping for the best. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, the project I'm working on is going to be distributed via PEAR, so I'll just list PHPUnit as a dependency in the package.xml file.  This will also allow the user some flexibility as to which version of PHPUnit she'd like to run her tests with.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty answered everything in the question. It's not a bug, it's a feature - the string @package_version@ is a placeholder that is replaced upon installing the package via PEAR.

Since you are using a version intended for development (repo clone from GitHub), you should be ready for issues like this.

If you want there some specific version instead, install this specific version via PEAR.

I can think of some post-checkout hook that would replace the string with revision sha1 hash, but that wouldn't be much useful.

So, in one sentence - it's intended to be this way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is no longer necessary.  From [PHPUnit 3.7.1's changelog](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.7.1/ChangeLog.md#phpunit-371):

> The version number is now displayed when using PHPUnit from a Composer install or Git checkout.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround, and yes it's not super-clean ;)

I have edited my phpunit file, don't forget to replace with your own paths :

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
while (substr(getcwd(), -3) != "Project_Folder") chdir('../');
if (in_array('--version', $argv)) {
    echo 'PHPUnit 3.6.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.';
    return;
}
// set main method
define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD','PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main');

// add phpunit to the include path
$paths = scandir('./var/lib/phpunit');
$includes = array();

foreach($paths as $path){
    if (!preg_match('/^\./', $path)){
        $includes[] = './var/lib/phpunit/' . $path;
    }
}
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$includes).PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());

// set the auto loader
require 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
// execute
PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
```